# Incomplete plot in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the feasible set of a maximization problem. One of the restrictions is incomplete as it should extend all the way to the x-axis.[image]

Also, I guess the `center` environment causes the whole figure+caption to be centered with respect to the page, but I was expecting the figure to be centered also with respect to the caption.

The MWE is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
   \begin{figure}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{axis}[
            ticks=none, 
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
            ymin=0,ymax=1.3]
         \addplot[
            domain = 0:sqrt(33/56),
            samples =200,
            smooth,
            blue,
            thick
            ] {sqrt((33/8-7*x^2)/3)};
         \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{This is text just to show that the figure is not centered with respect to the caption.}
   \end{figure}
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending @RaffaeleSantoro's answer:

Using `samples = 800` helps.

Also, don't put `figure` inside a `center` environment, but use `\centering` inside `figure` like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        ticks=none, 
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
        ymin=0,ymax=1.3]
        \addplot[
        domain = 0:sqrt(33/56),
        samples =800,
        smooth,
        blue,
        thick
        ] {sqrt((33/8-7*x^2)/3)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This is text just to show that the figure is not centered with respect to the caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not because the last point is not "reached". The function is not defined to the right of `sqrt(33/56)` and with a computers finite precision is not possible to evaluate the function at `sqrt(33/56)` either. -The point is discarded - look at the compile log. One possibility is to hugely increase the number of samples, so that second to last point gives an acceptable result. An other way is to define the point separately with a `y filter` Like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ticks=none, 
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
xmin=0,xmax=1.2,
ymin=0,ymax=1.3]
\addplot[
domain=0:sqrt(33/56),
samples=200,
smooth,
blue, thick,
y filter/.expression={x==sqrt(33/56)?0:y},
] {sqrt((33/8-7*x^2)/3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Quater circle in graph]

Comment: An other way is to increase the number of samples just before the zero point based on the steepness of the function with `samples at=...`, but there is no way to defined the sample points by a function.